# Add images via Shopware 6 API / VBA by URL

Tags: vba, api, ms-access, media, shopware

I try to use the Shopware 6 API to migrate things to a new shop from an existing Access Database using VBA with `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1`. Everything works fine except the media transfer.

My approach:

1. Create a media object in shopware in the right mediafolder

```
   POST /api/v3/media 

   payload: "{""mediaFolderId"":""" & folderID & """,""id"":""ec90cae2cc84c37b6b7a0cb9fe5c4548""}"
```

works fine!

2. Upload the new image (testfile.png) via url

```
   POST /api/v3/_action/media/ec90cae2cc84c37b6b7a0cb9fe5c4548/upload?extension=png&fileName=testfile

   payload: "{""url"":"" & MediaUrl & "." & MediaUrlExt & ""}"

   response 204 (no error),
```

A media file is created, but **the content of the file is not the PNG image but the payload string**.

the VBA code:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        AuthURL = url & "/api/v2/_action/media/" & newMediaID & "/upload?extension=" & FileExtFromUrl(MediaUrl) & "&fileName=" & FileNameFromUrl(MediaUrl) & "&_response=true"
        objHTTP.Open "POST", AuthURL, False
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & Token
        Debug.Print AuthURL
        payload = "{""url"":""https://" & FTPUrl & ftpKategorieOrdner & "/" & MediaUrl & """}"
        Debug.Print payload
        objHTTP.send (payload)
        strResult = objHTTP.responseText
        Debug.Print strResult
        Debug.Print "uploadMedia " & objHTTP.Status; " - " + objHTTP.StatusText
```

maybe creating the thumbnail is the problem? dev.log:

```
[2021-05-18 15:13:22] messenger.INFO: Sending message Shopware\Core\Content\Media\Message\GenerateThumbnailsMessage with Enqueue\MessengerAdapter\QueueInteropTransport {"message":"[object] (Shopware\\Core\\Content\\Media\\Message\\GenerateThumbnailsMessage: {})","class":"Shopware\\Core\\Content\\Media\\Message\\GenerateThumbnailsMessage","sender":"Enqueue\\MessengerAdapter\\QueueInteropTransport"} []
[2021-05-18 15:13:23] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\DebugClassLoader" instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The \"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\DebugClassLoader\" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use \"Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\DebugClassLoader\" instead. at ./vendor/symfony/debug/DebugClassLoader.php:16)"} []
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It's not a duplicate - uw ms tries to upload the image via URL (so Shopware downloads the image and inserts it to the library) - the linked question posts the image data.

Answer (score 0):

This should work - the admin panel uses the same endpoint for uploading a image via URL and for uploading the binary data.

The only difference I can spot is the content type of the request.

Unfortunately you did not mention which content type you are setting and I believe that is the problem.

[Only if the content type is `application/json`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/a51494c7b78d5f8163cdbbbe82f1a980461782db/src/Core/Content/Media/MediaService.php#L124), the file is fetched from the URL.

Make sure in the 2nd request to set the header

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

**EDIT** As per x-post in https://forum.shopware.com/t/bilder-upload-ueber-api-url/87850/4 it was found that VBA sends

```
content-type: "application/json; Charset=UTF-8"
```

So a possible patch for the Shopware core is

```
124: if (strpos($contentType,'application/json') !== false))
```

Comment: The content-Type is set. I added the complete code in my post.

Comment: @uwms Stange, then it should work. Are you able to use Xdebug and set a breakpoint in the function? If not, go the `var_dump($contentType); die()` route and see what's happening.

Comment: no clue if it's case sensitive. Try "Content-Type" instead of "Content-type" - but I believe that should not be the reason

Comment: @uwms did you find a solution?